# How to generate insert statements in a text file (*.sql) using sqlcmd

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sqlcmd

My operating system is Windows 7. I am working with SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have a database MyDB which has a table **employee_core** which has these columns: 
employee_id varchar(5), 
job_class smallint, 
location int, 
base_rate decimal(8,2), 
row_version rowversion, 
update_date datetime.

I want to be able to connect to this database, generate insert statements of all the data of some specific columns of this table and save those insert statements in a text file (*.sql) using `sqlcmd`. I would be running the `sqlcmd` from a Windows batch file outside of SQL Server Management Studio. How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

1. First write your query in a notepad then save it as .sql
2. create a batch file then type this

   `@echo off`
   `sqlcmd -S instance\Instance -d DATABASE NAME -U username -P password -i C:\INSERT.sql`

As soon as you run the batch file, it will trigger the `sqlcmd` then do the `INSERT.sql` if you don't have any error with your credentials.